# Translating text in external js file in Django

Tags: javascript, django

The project tree is as follows :

[image]

In the `url.py` inside `master` folder I have next:

```
from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog

......
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('traxio.traxio',),
}

url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
```

In my `base.html` file (`master/templates/master/base.html`) I added :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
<script src="/static/master/js/custom.js"></script>
```

If I click on page source when page loads I see :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/master/jsi18n/"></script>
<script src="/static/master/js/custom.js"></script>
```

The `custom.js` is the file where I need those translations.

I did :

```
django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l nl
django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l fr
django-admin compilemessages
```

The files are created in the locale folder. My custom.js is as follows:

```
function contactUs(fullname, telephone, email) {    
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: gettext("Limit reached"),
        message: '<p>gettext(You have reached the limit.)</p>',
        buttons: {
            .......
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But nothing happends. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding it to `master/urls.py` I added it to `traxio/urls.py` and I changed `packages`.

```
from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog

js_info_dict = {
    //domain is default
    'packages': ('traxio',),
}

urlpatterns = [
    .....
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

That did the trick.

If somebody else has the same problem hope this will help.

Comment: It appears as though Django switched to a CVB named JavaScriptCatalog.